# JQuery.each fails SOMETIMES

Tags: jquery

Looping over a bunch of checkboxes SOMETIMES fails.
The .each function is NOT entered when some or all boxes are checked so I get the "no checkboxes were checked" alert even though "checked" boxes exist.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submitme").click(function() {
    var urls = [];
    $("#edit :checked").each(function() {
      var obj = {};
      obj.url = $(this).val();
      urls.push(obj);
    });
    if (0 < urls.length) {
      $.post('/myurl', {urls: JSON.stringify(urls)});
    }
    else {
      alert("no checkboxes were checked!");
    }
   });
});

<div id="edit">
  <input type="checkbox" name="first"  value="first_url"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="second" value="second_url"/>
  <button id="submitme">submit</button>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8Xgmj/2/)

Comment: one minute ill double check this in a fiddle

Comment: Do you get errors when this happens, or can you reproduce the problem? Threw this into jsFiddle and it doesn't seem to have failed once...

Comment: your code looks ok, and does work! see my fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/heu96/

do you have other code on the page that might be interfering?  is this an exact copy of your code or did you retype it?
edit: ninja'd i swear neal and bjorn's comments werent there while i started typing this

Comment: It is funny this works in fiddle b/c when you pull it to an actual page it doesn't parse. The `if` is messed up.

Comment: Having updated the syntax with JSLint not complaining anymore the problem still persists.

Comment: I now realize that the problem exists in opera 11 EXCLUSIVELY, FF and IE both work (ALWAYS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No answer to the problem. The issue only exists in Opera so it's browser-related.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/BFuaZ/

Make sure there are no javascript errors anywhere else in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector should be 
    $("#edit input:checked")

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some syntax problems. Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submitme").click(function() {
    var urls = new Array();
    $("#edit :checked").each(function() {
      var obj = new Object();
      obj.url = $(this).val();
      urls.push(obj);
    });

    if (0 < urls.length){
      $.post('/myurl', {urls: JSON.stringify(urls)});
    }else {
      alert("no checkboxes were checked!");
   }
   });
   });
```

If you look in jsfiddle at the JSLint output you get this

```
Error:

Problem at line 2 character 25: Use the array literal notation [].

var urls = new Array();

Problem at line 4 character 21: Use the object literal notation {}.

var obj = new Object();

Problem at line 9 character 7: Expected '{' and instead saw 'console'.

console.log(urls)

Problem at line 9 character 24: Missing semicolon.

console.log(urls)

Problem at line 11 character 7: Expected '{' and instead saw 'alert'.

alert("no checkboxes were checked!");

Implied global: $ 1,3,5, console 9, alert 11
```